# How do ladder operators in harmonic oscillator problem manage to accomplish this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator

When we try to solve the harmonic oscillator problem by projecting the time independent equation onto position basis,we obtain solutions which do not vanish at infinity, then we ignore these solutions deliberately, but when we use ladder operators to solve the same problem, these undesired solutions are ignored automatically. I have been trying to understand how does approach manage to accomplish this. I tried different avenues of attack,the one which proved fruitful was the argument that eiegenvalues should be positive. I feel that this condition forces the eigenstates to behave well(because they should preserve hermiticity of position and momentum operators) but I am not sure how to make this argument concrete and rigorous(assuming that it's on the right track) . Attempts which try to answer this using the poisson bracket relations are less likely to be successful because, all those properties hold true even for undesired solutions

Comment: Eigenfunction of bound states by definition vanish at infinity. So what do you have in mind  when you say "we obtain solutions which do not vanish at infinity"? Are you talking about a general solution?

Comment: Yes when you just naively try to solve the differential equation ,you'll get solutions which are not normalizable, then we  should ignore them. But when we use operators and solve the same problem we seem to get only solutions which are normalizable. So i am asking how has this approach (like at which step exactly or what condition we imposed) enabled such filtration

Comment: You do not ignore solutions. You just look for the ones that solve your problem. In particular certain boundary conditions should be respected.

Comment: I understand that, that's what i mean by ignoring solutions, it's like ignoring the negative root if we are solving for time, but I think I have made my doubt adequately clear.